# React Redux Action Creator Dispatch Issue with Fetch API and Promise

Tags: react-redux

I am writing action creator in react app. where in when i do some api call i need to show the Progress Loader on screen. So, my action creator looks like this.

```
export const fetchData = (actionType, param) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.SHOW_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Show Loader Action
  return fetchDataRequest(actionType, param) // Here is Fetch APi Call
    .then(responseData => {
      dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER));
      dispatch(Action(recd(actionType), { data: responseData, receivedAt: Date.now() }));
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Hide Loader Action
    });
};
```

When i write this piece of code its working as expected, i am dispatching the action as dispatch(fetchData(data)) from component and i am able to show the loader in my Parent Component. What i understand is fetch is returning me the promise. Once the fetch gets completed then i am hiding the loader which is working as expected.

Now, There is scenario where in i need to do some validation where in i don't have to make any api call but all the validation are performed locally. 
Here also i want to do the same thing like i need to show loader in my parent component as well when all the validation are done i need to hide the loader.
I have written the same piece of code even actions are getting called but my render function is not getting called.
My Code Looks like:

```
// This my action creator which will actually do the validation
export const validateAndSaveData = () => {
  return ((dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let saveRecommendDetailsFlag = true;
      // here i am dispacthing some action and storing data in my store
      saveRecommendDetailsFlag = canSaveData(getState());
      if (saveRecommendDetailsFlag) {
        resolve('SUCCESS');
      } else {
        reject('ERROR');
      }
    });
  });
};
```

And there is one more action creator which i am calling it from from UI Component which will first initiate the show loader action and then perform validation and based on the result of validation i have to hide the loader.

```
export const saveData = () => {
  return ((dispatch) => {
   dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.SHOW_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Show Loader Action
    return dispatch(validateAndSaveData())
      .then(() => {
       // Here i m dispatching an action to do some more processing.
 dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Hide Loader Action
      })
      .catch(() => {
       dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Hide Loader Action
      });
  });
};
```

Everything is working fine but my loader are not coming on the screen. i am not able to figure it out where am i doing wrong.

Can anyone suggest something how can i solve this issue? 
I got some workaround using setTimeout func but i don't think that is right approach.

```
export const saveData = () => {
  return ((dispatch) => {
   dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.SHOW_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Show Loader Action
    setTimeout(()=>return dispatch(validateAndSaveData())
      .then(() => {
       // Here i m dispatching an action to do some more processing.
 dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Hide Loader Action
      })
      .catch(() => {
       dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER)); // Hide Loader Action
      });
},10);
  });
};
```

Comment: You have `validateAndSaveData` and `validateAndSaveOverviewDetails`, are they the same thing? If not, please post the code for `validateAndSaveOverviewDetails`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks reasonable, my suspicion is that your `validateAndSaveData` promise finishes so quickly that there is no visible loader on the screen.

In that case, a timeout is totally reasonable. However, in order to do it properly, I would keep a state on if the loading screen is visible + if it's been shown long enough. You can then remove the loading screen once it is both up for long enough, and the actual event expires.

I'm not sure which action package you're using, so I can't post exact code, but the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
const delay = (seconds) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds));


let loadingCounter = 0;
const showLoadingScreen = () => (dispatch) => {
  const counter = loadingCounter;
  loadingCounter++;

  delay(5).then(() => {
    if (getStore().loadingScreen.counter === counter) {
      dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.PROGRESS_LOADER_DELAY_ELAPSED))
    }
  })

  return dispatch(Action(ActionConstants.SHOW_PROGRESS_LOADER, counter))
}
```

Basically, you would keep track of 3 pieces of state for the loader:

```
{
  counter: 0,
  taskCompleted: false,
  canHide: false,
}
```

Counter is saved so that you can disambiguate what happens if you get SHOW_PROGRESS_LOADER while an existing SHOW_PROGRESS_LOADER is in progress. 
taskCompleted keeps a record of whether the thing you're waiting on is done, and canHide keeps track if the loader has been visible on the screen long enough.

When you dispatch `PROGRESS_LOADER_DELAY_ELAPSED` it sets canHide to true, and when you dispatch `HIDE_PROGRESS_LOADER` it sets taskCompleted to true. (although you may want to rename the latter action). When both `canHide` and `taskCompleted` are set to true, only then can the loader go away.

This is a pretty common UI pattern - Try to complete a task quickly. If it takes more than a short amount of time, then throw up a loading dialog. However, the loading dialog is guaranteed to stay up a minimum amount of time to prevent flickering. So the more advanced version of this kind of pattern would be to add another state which doesn't show the progress loader at all unless the call takes more than Y milliseconds.

Hope this makes sense, leave a comment if not :-)